# How to make a python POST response

Tags: python, api, click, command-line-interface

I am currently making a command line interface that has commands to interact with API endpoints that are on my flask webserver running on my local host. I am using Click for the framework of my CLI.

Some of my endpoints take only GET methods, while one takes GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.
I understand how to do the endpoints that just use the GET methods. An example of my code below:

```
@cli.command()
@click.argument('arg')
def factorial(arg):
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:80/factorial/{}'.format(arg)).json()
    print('input: {}, output: {}'.format(r['input'], r['output']))
```

Running this in a virtual environment in my terminal and the result:

```
(running the command) APICL factorial 1

(result) input: 1, output: 1
```

This works great. However I have a keyval endpoint that I would like to post json data to. I would like to be able to POST, PUT, and DELETE to this endpoint as well. But I am not sure how to properly do this. I know how to use curl to post data to this endpoint, for example:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:80/keyval -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"key":"1","value":"2"}'
```

I am trying to implement this logic into a click command line argument. Like how my first code example does for GET, but with POST functionality.

Comment: Use `request.post()` instead of `request.get()`.

Comment: and the same for `requests.put()`, `requests.delet()`, etc.